# Windows Store apps, save and load the state of Bing Maps Pushpins on navigation between pages

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, bing-maps

I'm making a Windows Store App that asks for user input then produces a bunch of pushpins based on that input. When a pushpin is tapped the app navigates to a page with more detail.

Now the problem i'm having is this:
My pages all inherit from the automatically generated LayoutAwarePage so I could potentially make use of SaveState and LoadState to save the pushpins so they don't get wiped on navigation. The thing is that i can't get the pins to save into the Dictionary object supplied by SaveState.

The error I get is "Value cannot be null" and it's referring to the _pageKey variable in LayoutAwarePage.OnNavigatedFrom() and i don't know why it's happening.

I've tried serialising them into a JSON string so i can deserialise it in LoadState, but i get the same result using a string or a List of UIelement.

I think this is all due to my lack of understanding of how SaveState, LayoutAwarePAge and SuspensionManager work. I thought what i was doing would work as the Dictionary is only asking for a string and an object.

I'm not using any other methods from LayoutAwarePage so if there is a better way than using SaveState and LoadState, I'm all ears.

These are the two versions of SaveState i've tried:

Using JSON

```
    protected override void SaveState(Dictionary<String, Object> pageState)
    {
        List<string> pindata = new List<string>();
        List<string> serialisedpins = new List<string>();
        foreach (Pushpin ele in map.Children)
        {
            pindata = ele.Tag as List<string>;
            serialisedpins.Add(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pindata));
        }

        string jasoned = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(serialisedpins);
        pageState["pins"] = jasoned;
    }
```

using a List of UIElement

```
    protected override void SaveState(Dictionary<String, Object> pageState)
    {
        List<UIElement> pins = new List<UIElement>(map.Children);
        pageState["pins"] = pins;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting (`_pagekey` value cannot be null) is not really related to what you're saving into the `Dictionary`. The exception is most likely being thrown in `OnNavigateFrom()` method of `LayoutAwarePage`:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    var frameState = SuspensionManager.SessionStateForFrame(this.Frame);
    var pageState = new Dictionary<String, Object>();
    this.SaveState(pageState);
    frameState[_pageKey] = pageState; // <-- throws exception because _pageKey is null
}
```

If you take a look at the rest of the code of `LayoutAwarePage` you'll find out the value of `_pageKey` is being set in `OnNavigatedTo` method of `LayoutAwarePage`:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    // Returning to a cached page through navigation shouldn't trigger state loading
    if (this._pageKey != null) return;

    var frameState = SuspensionManager.SessionStateForFrame(this.Frame);
    this._pageKey = "Page-" + this.Frame.BackStackDepth; <-- this line sets the _pageKey value

    if (e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.New)
    {
        // Clear existing state for forward navigation when adding a new page to the
        // navigation stack
        var nextPageKey = this._pageKey;
        int nextPageIndex = this.Frame.BackStackDepth;
        while (frameState.Remove(nextPageKey))
        {
            nextPageIndex++;
            nextPageKey = "Page-" + nextPageIndex;
        }

        // Pass the navigation parameter to the new page
        this.LoadState(e.Parameter, null);
    }
    else
    {
        // Pass the navigation parameter and preserved page state to the page, using
        // the same strategy for loading suspended state and recreating pages discarded
        // from cache
        this.LoadState(e.Parameter, (Dictionary<String, Object>)frameState[this._pageKey]);
    }
}
```

Usually the reason for that is that you're overriding `OnNavigatedTo` in your own page without calling `base.OnNavigatedTo(e)` inside it. The basic pattern of overriding it should always be:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    // the rest of your own code
}
```

This will make sure the base implementation will execute and set the `_pageKey` value as well as call `LoadState()` to load the previously saved state if there's any.

Comment: Thanks
I knew what varaible was causing the error and where, i just didn't realise that OnNavigatedTo had been overridden.
What had happened was i created the project as a blank page, then changed it to inherit form LayoutAwarePage rather than Page, so the OnNavigatedTo method was already there, unaltered.

Comment: I have the same problem. but i am calling 'base.OnNavigatedTo(e)'

Comment: @SaadAnees Your `_pageKey` value is `null`? Well, if you are calling `base.OnNavigatedTo`, try stepping through the method to determine why its value would remain `null`.

Comment: `protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            
            var frameState = SuspensionManager.SessionStateForFrame(this.Frame);
            var pageState = new Dictionary<String, Object>();
            this.SaveState(pageState);
            frameState[_pageKey] = pageState;
        }`

Comment: @SaadAnees That's Windows 8.1 template, code from `NavigationHelper.OnNavigatedFrom`? In this case `_pageKey` is initialized in `NavigationHelper.OnNavigatedTo`. It probably isn't called from your page's `OnNavigatedTo` as it should be. BTW, this discussion is more and more calling for a separate question.